# XAP build is not installing on Window Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, temenos-quantum

Does anybody know about building details for Windows Phone 8 in Kony Studio?.

I have installed all the requirements for Windows Phone 8 Device . But, I am unable to run on emulator due to Hyper V settings. Because my processor haven't Virtualization technology. Even though I can build and get XAP file for Windows Phone 8.

XAP File is installed successfully and but is not running. It closed after showed splash screen.

Comment: problem is not in the xap, the app might be getting an exception I guess. Check launching events

Comment: Try to debug your app right on device. I don't know anything about Kony, but there should be debugging mode or this tool is completely  useless.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal: I tried to show sample text only.Is developer account needed for launching app.I used general account for this.But, XAP is deployed.Is signing  needed for this XAP?

Comment: @crea7or: Yes,Debug mode is there.But it doesn't show anything?

Comment: you are able to see the splash screen that means the app is successfully launched, what happens after that is caused by something that comes under the app.

Comment: What @AmanKhandelwal says is right, your application installed just fine, but it is crashing on startup.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal: I u don't mind,Kindly share any sample app or source in Kony Studio Build.

Comment: My bad, I don't have anything built on Kony Studio

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal: But Same code is running on android device when building in kony studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, Kony fully supports using the Windows 8 emulator.  There are some configurations that you want to tweak to get it to work ( I've done it successfully myself. )

1. Before trying to run the emulator with Kony, make sure that you can start the Windows 8 emulator itself.
2. In the properties of your project, have the following setting: Properties - > Native - > Windows Phone 7 & Above - > Windows Phone 8 - > Application UI -> Supported Resolutions Label - > All the resolutions should be checked
3. You need to change the capabilities supported by the emulator; again, from the project properties: Properties - > Native - > Windows Phone 7 & Above - > Windows Phone 8 - > Application UI ->Capabilities - > 3 Capabilities should be removed : ID_CAP_GAMESERVICES, ID_CAP_WALLET_PAYMENTINSTRUMENTS, ID_CAP_WALLET_SECUREELEMENT
4. You need a publisher ID generated; again from project properties: Properties - > Native - > Windows Phone 7 & Above - > Windows Phone 8 - > Application UI ->Packaging->Publisher ID-> Id must be present.  Press the Generate button to create.

You then build your application, and use the Windows Phone Application Deployment tool, pointing the XAP to the build directory where your Win phone XAP was created.